# South African passport holder traveling from South Africa, via Luanda, Angola to Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

Tags: transit-visas, south-african-citizens, angola, lad

I am in transit for 3 hours in the airport in Luanda, Angola, on my way from Cape Town, South Africa to Rio in Brazil. I am on a South African passport.

Do I need an Angolan visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, thankfully you do not. Courtesy of [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm):

> / 14NOV16 / 1845 UTC
>
> National South Africa (ZA)      /Embarkation South Africa (ZA)
>   Transit Angola (AO)             /Destination Brazil (BR)
>     ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>    Angola (AO)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of
>   onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.